# Ruby on Rails (Michael Hartl) lesson no. 8 could not login as a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed RORT by Michael Hartl( to the letter) lesson 8 upto section 8.2.3 and i could not login as a user. Following is the error log that is generated

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  authenticity_token: ywHzc90gQ54IgmJpt+QdX43MEah/JAoVt93sSOFYAcZ/iVqXEle/eFWBrtDi9AqF77RBIMHYRbUVj87UBrtBHQ==
  session: !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
    parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      email: monster@railstutorial.org
      password: XXXXXXX
    permitted: false
  commit: Log in
  controller: sessions
  action: create
permitted: false
```

I am not able to understand what i did wrong

Code app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user=User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:email])
        log_in user
        redirect_to user
        #here
    else
        flash.now[:danger]="Invalid email/password combination"
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

Code app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

    def  log_in(user)
        session[:user_id]=user.id
    end

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
        @current_user
    end

    def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

end
```

Comment: That's not an error log, that's the printout of some submitted parameters. Can you share the code you have that performs the login?

Comment: so what happens when you try to login? "I could not login" isn't very explanatory.

Comment: @sevenseacat a flash is shown indicating invalid username/password

Comment: I think you have typo in this `if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:email])` line. It should be `if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])`. Right now you're trying to authenticate the user with the `email` provided as if it was the password.

Comment: @fanta that solved it. Thanks a bunch